# Handling Multiple tables Using Data flow dynamically

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, dataflow

I tried to use [this](http://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2019/05/azure-incremental-load-using-adf-data.html) article in successfully copying data from one table to another using Dataflows in Data factory. Now my scenario is to handle multiple tables in the DB. the above example is for one of the table.

I tried to follow the next article ([link](http://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2019/06/staging-with-azure-data-factory-foreach.html)) in same series and have created View and For each loop but now wondering how should I put the input in Data Flow activity.

Any ideas or if any one tried the same thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a parameterized dataset that uses a dataset parameter for the name of the table. Then, pass a string parameter from the Foreach activity that contains the table name into the dataset parameter for that data flow activity. This will all be accomplished from the pipeline.

Comment: Mind giving some more details... I still didnt get how you are going to pass a string parameter from Foreach each activity

Comment: It's described in step 8 in the article link that you included in the 2nd paragraph. Use the iterator from the foreach that is a string table name and pass it to the table name in the dataset parameter. In your case, just use a Data Flow activity instead of the Copy Activity in the example.

Comment: I fear I am still not able to figure out a way on how to do this. How will I map all my source table with each sink table

Comment: With Data Flows, you would use schemaless datasets for your Source and Sink transformations and either use "automap" on the Sink or write a rule using rule-based mapping to map columns based on patterns.

Comment: This video helps explain how to do it: https://youtu.be/Sj15Yjwai1A

Comment: Hi Mark, Great video but its still do not serve the purpose. In the article if you see I need to pass 'Table name' and 'LastEditedWhen' column in Derived and Join block, but using this method, I dont get the column names. It says column cannot be found though I have both columns in all my source tables in database. how should i solve this??

Comment: Without defined schemas in your data flow source, you won't have defined column names. You need to find the columns using patterns in Derived Columns using the expression functions byName() or byPosition(). Your Derived Column will define the column that you can then use in your transformations. See the Azure ADF docs on schema drift and pattern matching for more.

Comment: I did try that. Now I have listed my steps here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pfBwC4k5J0mnOi96LPj-2twquhYQ5V4c/view?usp=sharing     
 Maybe if you can have a look and help me out on Derived column part